# Dart library vs lib

Tags: shared-libraries, dart, project-structure

In Dart-land, what is the relationship between a `library` declaration and the `lib` directory inside the project? In other words, if my project has a structure like this:

```
myapp/
    lib/
        SomeType.dart
        src/
            SomeOtherType.dart
    web/
        AnotherType.dart
        another-type.html
```

And in `SomeType.dart` I have:

```dart
library myapp.logging;

class SomeType {
    // ...
}
```

...then what's the difference between the `myapp/lib` directory and *any* `library` declarations sprinkled throughout the Dart source code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ultimately, there is no relation between your directory structure and the library keyword in Dart.

The dart directory structure comes from the recommended 
[package layout conventions](http://pub.dartlang.org/doc/package-layout.html) but are not enforced by the language in any way. They are only enforced if you try to use the pub package manager to publish (upload) your package to the official dart repository. Ultimately you can use whatever directory structure layout you choose. This one is recommended to keep consistency between packages, particularly for Open Source packages or applications which may have other external contributors.

The `library` keyword in Dart is used in a way of namespacing. For instance the underscore private variables are only have library visibility. Anything in the same library can see/access your underscore variables. Anything outside of it cannot. You can use the `part` and `part of` keywords to make other files part of a library (regardless of where they are located in the directory structure).

Comment: Thanks @Matt B (+1) - so where do you declare/use the `library` keyword, and where do you use `part`/`part of`? To me, **every** file is a part of *some* library, yet there must be rules dictating when it is appropriate to use `library logging;` vs `part of logging;`, etc. Is it that some "master file" must declare `library`, making it the "head"/"entry point" of the library that all other files are a `part of`? Thanks again!

Comment: Unlike Java, Dart files can contain multiple classes to group classes as part of one library. However if they begin to get large and unwieldy then its benificial to use the `part` and `part of` to break one library with multiple classes into multiple files. See the new Dart URI package as an example of using parts: https://github.com/dart-lang/uri/blob/master/lib/uri.dart

Comment: Thanks @Matt B (+1 again) - so in that example, it declares a `library` named `uri`, and has several classes in it. It also mentions that it has 2 other `part`s: `uri_template.dart` and `uri_parser.dart`. **Does that mean that the classes defined inside `uri.dart` (e.g. `UriMatch`) can access anything defined inside `uri_template.dart` and `uri_parser.dart`?** I *think* I'm starting to get it...

Comment: Correct, and more so, vice-versa. Anything in uri_template and uri_parser can access anything (including `_variables`) in uri.dart. Here's another example from one of my projects: https://github.com/butlermatt/dart_koans/blob/master/bin/dart_koans.dart basically all the files are part of the same library but just because of the number of lines in each, they are broken up into related files (lists, numbers, strings, etc).

Answer (score 3):

The `lib` directory has no relationship with the `library` declaration.
You can declare a library consisting of one or more dart files no matter in which directory the files are stored.
Several files consisting one library don't need even to be stored in the same directory.

If you want to make a package available as a library the convention is to store the files consisting the public API in the `lib` directory and library private API in `lib/src`. Even here there could be several libraries in `lib` and several libraries in `lib/src`.

Comment: Thanks @Gunter Zochbauer (+1) - please see my question underneath Matt B's answer - I have the same question for you! Also, I've noticed that all of my Dart code snippets keep getting edited, but when I look at the diffs between what was edited and my original code, I don't see any differences...do you know what's going on there? Thanks again!

Comment: I edited your snippet just to add syntax highlighting ;)

Comment: You have one main file where you declare the library and additional files that are part of a library. I often have no code in the file where i declare the library but only the library declaration, the imports and the part of list. The actual code is in the parts.